# Linearize non-linear constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, lpsolve

### I have a problem which may be defined as:

```
max 5 x11 + 6 x12 + 2 x21 + 3 x22 st 
st.
x11,x12,x21,x22  binary
x11 + x12 = 1
x21 + x22 = 1
-25 x1 x2 >= 0
```

I want to check only if both x11 and x21 are 1.

How can I linearize this constraint? Or is it possible to linearize?

Thank you very much.

Comment: try to better format your post. Maybe make formulas code blocks. Also isn't this a math problem?

Comment: The last constraint makes no sense. What is the relation between ```x1, x2``` and ```x11, x12, x21, x22```? Are these variables also binary? Or are they (free) continuous variables?

Answer (score 0):

"I want to check only if both x11 and x21 are 1." How about:

```
x11 + x21 >= 1
```

instead of

```
-25 x1 x2 >= 0
```